# Validation Rule CASE() function

Tags: validation-rule

I have this validation rule which works perfectly :

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case1"), Probability != 100, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case2"),  Probability != 0, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case3"),  Probability != 10,
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case4"),  Probability != 20, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case5"),  Probability != 30, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case6"),  Probability != 40,
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case7"),  Probability != 50, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case8"),  Probability != 60, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case9"),  Probability != 70, 
IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName  , "Case10"),  Probability != 80, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Case11"),  Probability != 90, 
Probability = 0)))))))))))
```

As you can see if my StageName is "Case1" and my probability is not "100%", an error message will be send to the user.

My question is, how can i do the same work with the function CASE()?
I saw [Documentation about function Case()](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?siteLang=fr&id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0&language=en_us) but i don't understand how it works for my case in particular.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the `Probability !=` outside of the CASE, resulting in a much more legible formula:

```
(Probability*100) != CASE(StageName,
  "Case1", 100,
  "Case2", 0,
  "Case3", 10,
  "Case4", 20,
  "Case5", 30,
  "Case6", 40,
  "Case7", 50,
  "Case8", 60,
  "Case9", 70,
  "Case10", 80,
  "Case11", 90,
  IF(Probability=0,100,Probability))
```

Here, case returns a particular value (100, 0, etc), and it is compared to the Probability field as a percentage. The "default" condition is used to emulate "if stage is none of the prior values, and probability is zero, display an error".

Comment: Edit : @sfdcfox Actually i cannot save anything now, even if probability is relied to the good stage name i got the error message

Comment: @VERYNET This should definitely work, as I tested it in my dev org. Make sure that your spellings are correct.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it does not work. I did just one, Case1, 100 and when i do a modification by Case1 and probabilty 100% i have the error message

Comment: i found the problem Its "Case 1", 1.00 => because percentage, Case 3 "0.10" etc ...

Comment: @VERYNET Yeah, that's kind of odd behavior. I've edited the answer, but that should work for you.

Comment: no problem thanks your method was good, just needed an adjustment.